# Keras model multiple inputs and multiple outputs: how to determine multiple or non multiple scenario for input and output

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying keras in python. I want to know how to decide if my model is a multi input multi output model.
My input and target looks like the following

Input Table

```
......................inputs...............................     ..............targets............
Time     ID        FA_1    FA_2   FA_3   FA_4   FA_5    Tag     F_1     F_2    F_3    F_4    F_5
  1       2          4       0      3     7      0       0       1       0      1      0      0
  3       2          4       0      3     7      0       1       0       0      1      1      0
  2       7          0       5      6     0      2       1       0       1      1      0      0
```

here, FA values features with some count values in integer and F values are binary values of error occurrence on the features.

Now if i want to predict the target values with the given input values will it be a multiple inputs and multiple outputs model?

For clarification, for each row of inputs i want 5 values in the output. The values can be either predicted values (0 or 1) or predictions of being 1 (0-100%).

I checked keras documentation of  [Models with multiple inputs and outputs](https://keras.io/guides/functional_api/). But it has totally different outputs, where in my case its just multiple number of outputs not multiple outputs. Any relevant suggestions on building the model is appreciated.

may be something like this,

```
model = keras.Model(inputs=[input_table, tags_input],
                    outputs=[F_1_pred, F_2_pred, F_3_pred, F_4_pred, F_5_pred])
```